# Click and drag to scale a sprite in one direction at speed of mouse cursor in godot 2D

Tags: sprite, game-development, godot, gdscript, godot4

I would like to implement a scene consisting of a line sprite that can be adjusted in game by clicking on one end or the other of the line and then dragging that line sprite accordingly. The center position of the line should not move when dragging an end of the line, and the line should only scale up/down on the side being dragged rather than scaling up/down symmetrically from the center.

For reference, here is a video of my current behavior which I have been able to implement. It is close, but there are some issues

https://imgur.com/a/1PmnJzp

The associated code:

```
func _process(delta):
    if end_1_clicked:
        rotation = get_global_mouse_position().angle_to_point(position) + PI/2
        grow_or_shrink_value = get_global_mouse_position().distance_to(position) - position.distance_to($EndOneArea.global_position)
        if grow_or_shrink_value > 10:
            scale.y += angular_speed * delta
        elif grow_or_shrink_value < -10:
            if scale.y > 0.2:
                scale.y -= angular_speed * delta
    if end_2_clicked:
        rotation = get_global_mouse_position().angle_to_point(position) + PI/2
        grow_or_shrink_value = get_global_mouse_position().distance_to(position) - position.distance_to($EndOneArea.global_position)
        if grow_or_shrink_value > 10:
            scale.y += angular_speed * delta
        elif grow_or_shrink_value < -10:
            if scale.y > 0.2:
                scale.y -= angular_speed * delta
```

My line consists of an area2d having a single sprite child (one solid black line), a collision2d that I use to click and drag the main line, and 2 other children area2d, each with their own collision2d on either end of the sprite line, which I use to detect when a click is on the end of the line.

Right now, as can be seen in the video above, the rotation works fine but I have the scaling set to a constant value, resulting in weird feeling behavior if you move the mouse faster than the constant value, since the scaling speed does not keep pace with the mouse.

It can also be seen that the line scales symmetrically in both directions, rather than keeping the line fixed in position and only expanding out in one direction.

So I am wondering how I can get from the behavior that I currently have to the desired behavior?